# what does "target.href" mean in following pice of javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html

Code is here. aContextNav, aAddWebmark are id names.

```
function $(id){
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

var target = event.target != null ? event.target : event.srcElement;
$('aContextNav').href = target.href;
$('aAddWebmark').href = 'http://luke.breuer.com/webmark/?addurl=' +
encodeURIComponent(target.href) + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(target.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Probably the expended `href` of an `a` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML, [links](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#links) represent a connection between the document and some other resource. That resource is referenced using the `href` attribute.

Some examples:

```
<a href="http://example.com/foo">I am a hyperlink</a>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
```

The `href` content attribute is reflected by a `href` IDL attribute, so in JavaScript you can use it as a property of the element, in this case, the target of an event.

The [target](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-event-target) of an event is the element in which the [event](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event) was [dispatched](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event-dispatch).